# Unsupervised Odd-one-out - paper recommendation

Tags: neural-networks, clustering, medicine

**Abstract Problem:** I have several series (sharing the same class) of about 400 small images each. Each one of my series has >390 images, that belong together. The rest of the images shares the style of its series, however **may** include something, which makes it look odd from the human eye perspective.

Is it possible to detect, if a new series of images contains an odd looking image?

**Example:**

You have people and take 400 high resolution images of their skin of their arm. The image do not overlap. Most images (>390) will not show anything interesting, however some may indicate a desease, that will be noticeable, especially if it's repeating across multiple people. I don't know, which of these images looks odd, but I know, if a person has a desease or does not have one.

**Thus far:**

My first idea was to use some sort of cluster algorithm. It is unsupervised and thus functional for the problem. Via transfer learning I create a good feature space of my images, maybe reduce the dimensionality of it, cluster them and hope there will be 2 well seperated kernels, that contain 10 or about 390 samples each.
This method also has another advantage: It can be done fairly quickly, no training of some model etc. is necessary.

My second idea would be to cross compare all images inside a series, but overall it would follow a similar path from my 1st idea. The hope is that the difference between two not-odd images is fairly boring, while comparing odd and not odd is noticeable.

3th: Use some outlier detection using Autoencoders/GANs.

**Question:** Is there a deep learning approach for this type of problem? At the moment all my ideas revolve around one single series, however all series belong to the same class - which has to be somehow useable. Is someone familiar with this kind of problem? Are Odd-one-out networks is useable/applicable in this situation? To my knowledge however, they are self-supervised and thus maybe not the right tool.

I would be really happy, if someone with more experience than me, could point in one reasonable direction and recommend me something for further reading. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic case of "local outlier detection". You have a set of images, but a few objects divert a little bit more than the others.

There exist some deep learning approaches for this, but they seem to mostly work for images (read: they work on MNIST). As I don't use images, I have not further studies them.

As a starting point for **local outlier** detection prior to deep learning, see this overview that discusses some applications (there is video in there, but IIRC not deep learning):

> Schubert, E., Zimek, A., & Kriegel, H. P. (2014). Local outlier detection reconsidered: a generalized view on locality with applications to spatial, video, and network outlier detection. Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery, 28(1), 190-237.

Comment: This is already a huge help!! Thank you very much. Once a direction is given, everything else will follow from that.